# USB type C not working

Tags: kali-linux, drivers, usb, kernel-modules

I connected an external Numpad with a USB type C plug into my laptop and it doesn't work. I've tried the Numpad on a system running Windows and it works just fine.

I tried a couple of solutions on the internet:

```bash
modprobe thunderbolt
modprobe intel-wmi-thunderbolt
```

And even though the modules loaded successfully the USB type C port is still not working.

I'm running:

```bash
uname -a

Linux 6.0.0-kali6-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.12-1kali1 (2022-12-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Running `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` while plugging in the numpad doesn't show anything in the output.

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Sorry for not giving out more information, I don't exactly know where to look so if you need more information please tell me what to run and I will update the question.

UPDATE:

```bash
lsusb                                                                                                                21:18:47
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c8:03a0 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 258a:0049 BY Tech Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

---

lsusb -t                                                                                                             21:18:52
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

```bash
cat /boot/config-6.0.0-kali6-amd64 | grep CONFIG_TYPEC                                                               21:25:56
CONFIG_TYPEC=m
CONFIG_TYPEC_TCPM=m
# CONFIG_TYPEC_TCPCI is not set
CONFIG_TYPEC_FUSB302=m
# CONFIG_TYPEC_WCOVE is not set
CONFIG_TYPEC_UCSI=m
CONFIG_TYPEC_TPS6598X=m
# CONFIG_TYPEC_ANX7411 is not set
# CONFIG_TYPEC_RT1719 is not set
# CONFIG_TYPEC_HD3SS3220 is not set
# CONFIG_TYPEC_STUSB160X is not set
# CONFIG_TYPEC_WUSB3801 is not set
# CONFIG_TYPEC_MUX_FSA4480 is not set
CONFIG_TYPEC_MUX_PI3USB30532=m
# CONFIG_TYPEC_MUX_INTEL_PMC is not set
CONFIG_TYPEC_DP_ALTMODE=m
CONFIG_TYPEC_NVIDIA_ALTMODE=m
```

UPDATE2: the output of `lsusb` doesn't differ before and after plugging in the Numpad.

Also tried flipping the plug, no luck.

Comment: Any info from dmesg or kernel logs ? + *"Trying to use"*… to what purpose ?

Comment: I just connected an external numpad which had the USB type C plug.
Running `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` while connecting the plug doesn't show anything.
I've tried the numpad with Windows and it works just fine.

Comment: Find your kernel .config file ang then *grep CONFIG_TYPEC .config* What does it tell ?

Comment: Run `lsusb` before plugging in the numpad, and again after plugging it in. Does the second run show any difference? Also, try flipping the USB-C plug over and plugging it in in the second possible orientation: if the numpad maker has been cheap, there might be just one pair of USB data lines connected.

Comment: updated and thanks